# How do I make a button redirect [HTML]

Tags: html, button, click, icons

This is my "Button"

```
<li><a href="#" class="icon fa-cogs"><span class="label">Dashboard</span></a></li>
```

Demo - https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZutL.gif

I need that button to redirect to a page what would I add in?

Comment: why don't you just treat that button as a link?

Comment: I don't quite see how that gif is a "demo".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Answer (score 1):

```
<li><a href="http://example.com/" class="icon fa-cogs"><span class="label">Dashboard</span></a></li>
```

Replace http://example.com/ with whatever page you'd like to redirect to.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><a href="link/to/page" class="icon fa-cogs"><span class="label">Dashboard</span></a></li>
```

For Example 
`<li><a href="/page/examples/" class="icon fa-cogs"><span class="label">Dashboard</span></a></li>`